# Rails Search form works only after reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a search form in Slips view witch displays dynamically results for Anagraphic model in a div. The problem is that when the slips index page is loaded for the first time, the search is not working dynamically, but only after press search button. After I reload the page, the search works fine, displaying results dynamically after I type characters in search field.

This is my Anagraphic model

```
def self.search(search)
 if search
  where('description LIKE :search OR code LIKE :search ', search: "%#{search}%")
 else
   all.limit(2)
 end
end
```

This is my SlipsController:

```
def index

  @visibleanagraphics = Anagraphic.where("laundryowner_id = ?", current_owner.id)
  @anagraphics = @visibleanagraphics.search(params[:search])

  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
   format.html
  end

end
```

In my slips Index view I have:

```html
<%= form_tag '/slips', :method => 'get', :id => "anagraphics_search" do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :autocomplete => :off %>
  <%= submit_tag "°", :description => nil, class:"btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

  <div id="anagraphics">
    <%= render "anagraphics" %>
  </div>
```

The results are displayed in this partial:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Codice</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th colspan="1"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @anagraphics.each do |anagraphic| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= anagraphic.code %></td>
          <td><%= anagraphic.description %></td>
          <td><%= anagraphic.customer %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'crea cedolino', {controller: 'slips', action: 'new', aid: anagraphic.id}, class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the javascript code slips.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#anagraphics_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#anagraphics_search").attr("action"), $("#anagraphics_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

And finally my index.js.erb:

```
$("#anagraphics").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("anagraphics")) %>")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have turbolinks enabled. This will affect your jQuery's `$(document).ready(function () {...})` call, since turbolinks basically caches the page and only reloads the whole page when you refresh, which is what is why it is probably working *after* you do so.

Good option is to try and use `gem jquery.turbolinks` which is intended to solve this issue. See how to include it in your app at the following link:

https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have this error by turbolinks. Try this instead `ready`

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $("#anagraphics_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#anagraphics_search").attr("action"), $("#anagraphics_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```